# How can I parse an external XML file with django/python

Tags: python, xml, django, parsing, django-models

I've done some research on trying to parse an XML file from another web server and came across something called [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

I've tried implementing this in my view.py file:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import models

def test(request):

    data={}
    doc=minidom.parse("http://www.someotherdomain.com/XML.aspx?id=27550&limit=100")
```

The problem I'm running into is I get the error `Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://www.someotherdomain.com/XML.aspx?id=27550&limit=100'`

I haven't been able to find out if you can use minidom on an external document or if it's only for documents located on the same server.

If this is not possible or is not the ideal solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently minidom cannot parse URLs. You have to do

```
import urllib2
doc = urllib2.urlopen(your_url)
parsed = minidom.parse(doc)
```